# I can't seem to make a Socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm new to Sockets.io and working on creating a real-time chat API. While using Sockets.io I can't seem to break into it.

```
const app = require("../app");
const debug = require("debug")("app:server");
const http = require("http");

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "5000");
app.set("port", port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Socket.io Connection
 */

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8,
});
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
```

Down Here I'm expecting a console Log, but I get nothing.
I don't get what's wrong here.

```
  console.log("New Socket IO Connection!!");
});

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
console.log("Serve Like a Server");
server.listen(port);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that atleast one client is connected to socket. Your code doesn't seems to be wrong here. You can check the working code for socket below.

bin/www

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('socketio:server');
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket.io');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Create Socket.io Connection.
 */

var io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: "*"
  }
});
require('../socket')(io);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

module.exports = io;
```

socket.js

```
module.exports = (io) => {
    let users = {}
    io.of('/test').on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('Connected', socket.id);
        socket.on('join', (data) => {
            socket.join(data.room);
            
            users[socket.id] = data;

            io.of('/test').to(data.room).emit('message', `${data.name} joined ${data.room} room!`);
        })
        
        socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
            io.of('/test').emit('message', 'user disconnected ' + users[socket.id].name);
            delete users[socket.id];
            console.log('Disonnected', socket.id);
        })
    })
}
```

You can check the full implementation [here](https://github.com/abhishekpankar/socket-io)

Comment: Thank You Abhishek Bhai, I didn't format the code to trigger the following code properly, hence I didn't get any response io.on("connection", function (socket) {
 
  console.log("New Socket IO Connection!!");
});